# Display real time clock and check string length

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing this program to auto save data to Postgres database when QT Text Edit detects the length of string is greater than 5 characters. The program also displaying current date and time.

note: I had created a save button for save the data in QT Text Edit. But actually I need the data to be saved once the QT Text Edit detects the length is more than 5 characters.

I am facing the difficulties as below:

1. The time displayed is stop, it is called and show when the apps is launched but after that it is just showing static.
2. the " if len(self.barcode_in) >= 5: " in line 106 is having error.

I did research on Python schedule, but seems like the minimum interval for scanning is 0.5 seconds. Do I need to use threading function to refresh the clock displayed and scan the length of QT Text Edit?
My full code is as below.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'savebarcodedatetime.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLCDNumber

import threading
import psycopg2
#from config import config
from threading import Thread
from datetime import  *
import time
from time import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)

        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 721, 531))

        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)

        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.show_time = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.widget) #LCD = show_time

        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setPointSize(16)

        self.show_time.setFont(font)

        self.show_time.setObjectName("show_time")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.show_time)

        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)

        self.show_date = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)

        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setPointSize(16)

        self.show_date.setFont(font)

        self.show_date.setObjectName("show_date")

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.show_date)

        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)

        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.widget)

        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem4)

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.barcode_in = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)

        self.barcode_in.setObjectName("barcode_in")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.barcode_in)

        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem5)

        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)

        font = QtGui.QFont()

        font.setPointSize(24)

        self.save_button.setFont(font)

        self.save_button.setObjectName("save_button")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.save_button)

        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem6)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)

        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))

        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)

        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")

        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)



        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        

        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_db)

       

        printoutput.printoutmessage()

        

        todaydate = QTime.currentTime()

        print(todaydate.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate))

        todaydate_str = todaydate.toString("H:mm:ss")

        self.show_date.setText(todaydate_str)



        

        print(todaydate.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate))

        

        

        if len(self.barcode_in) >= 5:

                barcodedata = self.barcode_in.toPlainText()

                insertdb.insert_vendor(barcodedata)

                print('barcode save')

        

       

                



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

        self.show_date.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

        self.save_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))

        

        

    def save_db(self):

        print("save")

        #mytext = self.textEdit.toPlainText()

        barcodedata = self.barcode_in.toPlainText()

        insertdb.insert_vendor(barcodedata)

        #barcode_in = ''

        today = datetime.now()

        print (today.strftime(' %a %d-%m-%Y @ %H:%M:%S'))

        

class insertdb:

        

    def insert_vendor(vendor_name):

        """ insert a new vendor into the vendors table """

        sql = """INSERT INTO vendors(vendor_name)

             VALUES(%s) RETURNING vendor_id;"""

        conn = None

        vendor_id = None

        try:

           conn = psycopg2.connect(host="192.168.1.104", 

                port = 5432, database="suppliers", 

                user="pi", password="1234")

           cur = conn.cursor()

           # execute the INSERT statement

           cur.execute(sql, (vendor_name,))

           # get the generated id back

           vendor_id = cur.fetchone()[0]

           conn.commit()

           cur.close()

        except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:

           print(error)

        finally:

           if conn is not None:

               conn.close()



        return vendor_id

        

class printoutput:

        def printoutmessage():

                print("print output")





if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    ui = Ui_MainWindow()

    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qtextedit can emit signals every time the text on it changes, [here is the name and doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textChanged).

My suggestion is to connect that signal to you self-defined slot and in the implementation of that method check the length of the new text... is more efficient than polling every "x" seconds for the size of a string.

Now, to the error here:

```
if len(self.barcode_in) >= 5:
```

is not valid since

`self.barcode_in` is actually a widget, you initialized it like doing
`self.barcode_in = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget)` therfore makes no sense to compare it against a number, but what you want is to compare the len of the text in that widget, and for this you need the "plain-text" of it ([here the doc for that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop))

Comment: Hi, do you mind to show me how to write the textChanged event? just need a short example for reference because i cant understand the QT document.
for the data in QT widget, is that possible i can call the textEdit outside of the class? then i might able to compare the len outside of that class. For the class UI_MainWindow, i generated it from QT ui file, then i add in other python code. that's why i not really sure how should i edit it.

Comment: Hi, i able to found the example for textchanged already.

Comment: my code is " self.barcode_in.textChanged.connect(self.checktextlength)" trigger another method, checktextlength. Thank you very much for your help. 
Another thing is the display of real time clock. is there any suggestion you can give me?